# Mocha testcase is not running on chrome browser when we use import module in test spec files

Tags: google-chrome, mocha.js

We have been working on mocha and chai to write the unit test cases for the typescript project. But when we use the import module statement in the test spec file and launch html to run test cases on the browser, the mocha interface loads but no test cases run on the browser. It keeps on showing passes: 0
failures: 0
duration: 0s and the browser doesn't even throw some error to point out the exact issues.[Browser snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkMhp.png)
If we go to the sources folder in the browser then the test spec file, chai.js, and mocha.js load successfully.
Official steps have been followed to integrate the mocha and chai test cases.

Here is the sample code structure:

index.ts:

```
export class SampleClass {
  sayHello() {
    return "Hello, world!";
  }
}
```

SampleSpec.ts

```
import { SampleClass } from "../src/index.js";
var expect = chai.expect;
var assert = chai.assert;
describe("Sample", () => {
  it("says hello", () => {
    console.log("Inside it block");
    const sample = new SampleClass();
    const result = "Hello";
    expect(result).to.equal(sample.sayHello);
  });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- <script src="../node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chai@4.2.0/chai.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mocha@10.2.0/mocha.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <script type="module" src="../test/Castor.spec.js"></script>
    <script>
      mocha.setup("bdd");
      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",                                  
    "module": "ES2020",                                
    "esModuleInterop": true,                            
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            

    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  }
}
```

Note: It is working on safari and giving the right results of unit testing but not running on chrome browser.

Can someone help what's the issue here when running on chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me as I was moving a three.js CLI mocha suite into the browser and I was able to sort it by adding `type="module"` on the working mocha.run() call.

I have broader questions about why that would be the case. YMMV.